# httpurlConnection.getContentLength() return -1

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I want to download a pic from the internet in this IP:
http://redsonic.skyf.ir/testdownload.jpg

But my `httpurlConnection.getContentLength()` returns -1.

Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(downloadPath);
HttpURLConnection httpConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpConnection.connect();

File file = new File(filePath);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8*1024];
int len=0;
int downloadsize = 0;
int filesize = httpConnection.getContentLength();
while ((len=inputStream.read(buffer))>0)
{
    outputStream.write(buffer,0,len);
    downloadsize += len;
    float persent = (float) downloadsize/filesize;
    Log.i("***","downloadsize="+downloadsize + "   filesize="+filesize+"    percent = "+persent);
}
//outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

But when I download other pictures from the internet it works.

How is it possible?

Comment: Your code is invalid. You're setting the request method to GET, but then you're setting `doOutput` to true, which sets it to POST, but then you aren't sending any output. You need to fix two out of three of these issues and retest.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks EJP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete line : `httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);` **or** set false

[Thanks EJP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp)

Answer (score -1):

there is no wrong. I have tried my computer. httpurlConnection.getContentLength() returns 847. if you make request too much, you may have exceeded the maximum number of connections.